# "%02d" in android application code

Tags: java, android, eclipse, format

Application code is

```
DateTime startDate8 = DateTime.now(); 
DateTime endDate8 = new DateTime(2014, 11, 5, 15, 0);

Period period8 = new Period(startDate8, endDate8, PeriodType.dayTime());

PeriodFormatter formatter8 = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
    .appendMinutes()
    .toFormatter(); 

tw.setText(String.format("%02d",formatter8.print(period8)));
```

Application dont work.
App has stopped unfortunately. What is problem in my code?

Comment: Start with the stacktrace. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: LogCat http://i.imgur.com/5TQcLGV.png

Comment: Please paste it as (copyable, searchable) **text**, not a screenshot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`PeriodFormatter.print()`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatter.html#print%28org.joda.time.ReadablePeriod%29) returns a `String` (and `"%02d` requires a `int`). I think you wanted something like

```
 // tw.setText(String.format("%02d",formatter8.print(period8))); 
tw.setText(formatter8.print(period8));
```

Or, parse the `String` to an `int` like

```
try {
    int val = Integer.parseInt(formatter8.print(period8));
    tw.setText(String.format("%02d",val));
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    nfe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What if they really do want it zero filled?

Comment: @Tahakörkem Edited. I think the second example should do that.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch app stopped unfortunately when tw was empty

Comment: Posted code doesn't read `tw`. If you do somewhere, add a test for empty.

Comment: how i add test for empty

Comment: I don't know, I don't know what your code reading `tw` does. You should probably ask another question. Include the code that stops (presumably where are you reading `tw`) and the logcat in the question. Maybe include what you tried as a test for empty. My guess would be `tw != null && tw.getText().length() > 0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64352/discussion-between-taha-korkem-and-elliott-frisch).